# Why does this loop and append to data frame not work?

Tags: r, loops

I've done a similar operation many times, yet this example has me perplexed. Why does this not work? My expected output is an avg per row of avgs

```
library(dplyr)

for(i in 1:3) {
  avgs = data_frame('avgs' = rep(NA,3))
  avg = mean(rnorm(100, .6 , 6.8))
  avgs[i, ] = avg
}
avgs
```

Comment: Because the first thing you do in the loop is set `avgs = data_frame('avgs' = rep(NA,3))`, which overwrites whatever `avgs` was before and creates a new data frame. `i = 1`? New data frame. `i = 2`? New data frame. etc.

Comment: I am not sure about your intention. `avgs` should be a data frame with one column only storing what? Also, at each iteration you are re-initializing `avgs`, so I guess one thing you should modify regardless of the desired output is to move `avgs = data_frame('avgs' = rep(NA,3))` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Of course! It's been a long day. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixing your code:

```
library(dplyr)

avgs = data_frame('avgs' = rep(NA,3))
for(i in 1:3) {
  avg = mean(rnorm(100, .6 , 6.8))
  avgs$avgs[i] = avg
}
avgs
```

Why avoid loops:

```
library(microbenchmark)

rows = 3
avgs = data_frame('avgs' = rep(NA,rows))

loop <- function(df) {
  for(i in 1:rows) {
    avg = mean(rnorm(100, .6 , 6.8))
    df$avgs[i] = avg
  }
  return(df)
}

vectorize_it <- function(df) {
  df$avgs <- replicate(rows,mean(rnorm(100, .6 , 6.8)))
  return(df)
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(loop(avgs),vectorize_it(avgs))

rows = 3e3
avgs = data_frame('avgs' = rep(NA,rows))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(loop(avgs),vectorize_it(avgs))
Unit: microseconds
               expr     min       lq     mean   median      uq      max neval
         loop(avgs) 242.936 252.3650 392.8930 271.5235 326.749 4987.736   100
 vectorize_it(avgs) 138.131 142.1365 290.6037 155.3900 184.079 4804.938   100
> 
> rows = 3e3
> avgs = data_frame('avgs' = rep(NA,rows))
> 
> microbenchmark::microbenchmark(loop(avgs),vectorize_it(avgs))
Unit: milliseconds
               expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval
         loop(avgs) 281.02566 294.74691 345.14865 315.18423 347.36404 847.0420   100
 vectorize_it(avgs)  41.90678  43.51001  55.31815  47.26524  56.92735 167.4951   100
```

Comment: I am aware there are other ways to do it... but not completely aware as to why they would be better. Would you care to offer an example of an alternative method and explanation?

Comment: I edited my response to show how much more efficient vectorizing is vs loops especially when the vectors are longer.

Comment: awesome, thanks!